# How to configure Sitecore EXM to facilitate domain specific Send From Email IDs

Tags: exm

We are on Sitecore ExM 3.5.1 on Sitecore 8.2 Update 6.

We are in the process of setting up our production environment. We want the *Send From* email address to be domain specific.

noreply@domain1.com
noreply@domain2.com

We are using Sitecore Email Cloud.

How do we configure different *Send From* Email IDs per domain?

Comment: 2 email campaign manager root items can allow you to have different settings per domain.

Comment: @Anton the From Email on the Manager Root is set but its more related to the Sitecore Email Cloud. The emails going out end up in spam for email addresses on the same domain. For instance if the From Email is noreply@mydomain.com, all users who have mydomain.com do not get the email.

Comment: @ASura Do each domains being used have the appropriate DKIM keys set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for messages going into SPAM is because Email Clients aren't able to validate the sending email server versus the domain keys set on the domain.

In Sitecore EXM, there is a Domains page where you register all of the domains that Sitecore Cloud EDS is using. Each one will provide DKIM keys that need to be *correctly* added to the domain of each sending domain.

Short of that, the From Email Address is configured in the Email Manager Root, although you may also manually specify a From Email Address when creating an email campaign. It is best practice to have a separate Manager Root for each Domain that you are sending from.

And while not a requirement of Sitecore Cloud EDS, it is best practice to setup appropriate SPF records too.